# Use fully qualified type names in UML class diagrams

Tags: uml, class-diagram

According to UML (or its standard usage), it is better to use fully qualified names (namespace::type_name) for attribute types and operation parameters in the class diagrams. I have special interest in third party data types. For example: I'm working with OpenCV in my application, should I put cv::Mat or just Mat in the class diagrams?

Thanks in advance for any help and/or suggestion.

Comment: "It Depends". Is `Mat` likely to be unambiguous everywhere in the program? Then you can probably skip the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the readership. If your diagrams are all in a certain context where you can expect people to know that `Mat` is an OpenCV class, you can probably omit it. Further, UML tools are able to optionally show the FQN, so you can turn that on or off.